# How to create an excel file and attach in mail without store in local disk

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Using maatwebsite I have to generate the 'xlsx' file and attach the same in the email through mailable or direct mail attachment.

By default the file is stored in storage folder which I don't want.

Ignored the export or download method at the end of the script and assigned that Excel::create in a variable.

```
$file = Excel::create($fileName, function($excel) use($valuesInArray) {
    $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($valuesInArray) {
        $sheet->fromArray($valuesInArray);
    });
});

Mail::send('email.documents_export',["user"=>"Albert", "clientName" => "AAA"],function($m) use($file){
    $m->to('albert@aaa.com')->subject('Document Export');
    $m->attach($file->store("xlsx",false,true)['full']);
});
```

File has to be available for attachment without store it anywhere.

Comment: Went through the package. `Store` needs a path or uses the path from config. I am curious to know why you don't want it to be stored somewhere?

Comment: Because I don't need the file anymore. Its a additional storage for application server. Manually or some Script should delete those files later.

Comment: Why not encapsulate that logic in a `Job` that gets dispatched on a queue?

Comment: How come the Job and Queue are related with this question ?

Comment: `store()` needs a path and it seems you are worried that you need to write a script or delete those *temporary* files later on. Encapsulating this logic in a Job (creating mailable, attaching file, deleting file) and dispatching it into a Queue for async processing would be a good solution imo.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the "store" method you should use the "string" one.

Here is what the "string" method does from the library code:

```
ob_start();

$this->writer->save('php://output');

return ob_get_clean();
```

So in your email code you should write something like this:

```
$file = Excel::create($fileName, function($excel){
   // Your code here
});

Mail::send('email.documents_export',["user"=>"Albert", "clientName" => AAAA"],function($m) use($file){
    $m->to('albert@aaa.com')->subject('Document Export');
    $m->attachData($file->string("xlsx"), $fileName);
});
```

It took me a couple hours to get through this... The official doc didn't mention this method.

Bye =D